# Changing the speed of asPieProgress without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Is it possible to change the speed of this jQuery plugin's animation without reloading the page?

```
  function setPie(t) {
    $('.pie_progress--slow').asPieProgress({
      namespace: 'pie_progress',
      goal: 1000,
      min: 0,
      max: 1000,
      speed: t * 600,
      easing: 'linear'
    });
  }
```

As you can see I tried to wrap its initialization in a function which I call with a different t on some events like pressing a button etc, but it refuses to change its speed after it was initialized on the first function call.

On a side note, it's surprisingly hard to find a circular progress bar js plugin that would allow me to pause it and to resume any time (ProgressBar.js doesn't allow even it) and also would allow me to change its speed on the fly...

Answer (score 0):

w/e, i have solved it, apparently that plugin has a destroy() method, after using it i have to use $().empty() though on the whole div with rewriting html again because otherwise it creates a new svg ring but w/e